# awk reparse piped input without getline

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I wrote an awk script that will parse piped input and turn it into a well spaced table.
To achieve this I needed to parse the input stream twice. First to parse the actual column size for each column. And then for printing the table itself.

```
#!/bin/gawk -f
# with changes from ooga

BEGIN {
    FS=" "
    buffer = "mktemp" | getline result
    # Initialize Vars
}

{
    # Count Columns...
}

END{
    close(buffer)

    while((getline < buffer) > 0){
        # Print formated table
    }
}
```

So this is working but it uses `getline` and all manuals pointed out that there are very few cases where you *really* need `getline`. Thought the only other option I found was using files instead of pipes.

*Is there another option in `gawk` that will parse piped input twice?*

Comment: Can you show your input and expected output?

Comment: the script works like `column` the difference is that my script will create borders by using `+-|`.
But it works alright! I just wondered if one really needs the tempfile and `getline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a better way to do it (EDIT: actually, it's probably better to use an array as Ed Morton has said; see his post and my alternate example at the end of this post), but it's not a very "awkish" program since it doesn't use the `pattern{action}` paradigm. The only advantage of `awk` for this program is the automatic field-splitting.

Some tips:

- `FS` defaults to a single space (which has the special meaning that fields are separated by runs of whitespace and that leading and trailing whitespace is ignored.) So there's no need to explicitly set it to a space.
- `|&` opens a coprocess, but you only need a regular pipe so just ust `|`.
- You should explicitly close the pipe.
- The function seems an unecessary complication.
- You should delete the temporary file after you're finished with it.

This yields:

```
#!/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
    "mktemp" | getline tmpfile
    close("mktemp")
}

{
    # process and save piped data to tmpfile
}

END {
    close(tmpfile)
    while((getline < tmpfile) > 0) {
        # process data from tmpfile
    }
    system("rm " tmpfile)
}
```

---

Here's an example of using an array instead of a temporary file:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

{
    line[NR] = $0
    if (NF > nf)
        nf = NF;
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
        if (length($i) > flen[i])
            flen[i] = length($i)
}

END {
    for (r=1; r<=NR; ++r) {
        for (f=1; f<=nf; ++f) {
            split(line[r], fields)
            printf("| %-*s ", flen[f], fields[f])
        }
        print "|"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat file
one two three
four five six
seven eight nine
$ cat file | ./columnize.awk
| one   | two   | three |
| four  | five  | six   |
| seven | eight | nine  |
$
```

Comment: ok thanks for those tipps gonna do that. Forgot about that tempfile.
If you say not very awkish is there a better choice like `sed` because bash turns out really slow.

Comment: @mjb4 `sed` is not going to be useful for this. See Ed Morton's post and the second example added to mine for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the input in an array and then print that. You didn't post any sample input and expected output so there's nothing we can test against but something like this might be what you want:

```
awk '
{
    line[NR] = $0
    curLength = length($0)
    if (curLength > maxLength)
        maxLength = curLength
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
        printf "| %*s |\n", maxLength, line[i]
    }
}
'
```

Comment: +1 I was going to say that but wanted to explore the whole piping, getline thing. Also I thought if the data was very large storing it in memory might not be the best. But then again, how large is it likely to be? And virtual memory would handle it anyway. I think he actually wanted the max size of each field (and perhaps the max number of fields) but I'm not sure.

Comment: Arrays was the first thing that I tried but then I thought it's propably a slow approach

Comment: But still I got that script running was just wondering if there is an idiom or common approach on this kind of situation.

Comment: Use of arrays would not be slow and using an array is the idiomatic approach. If you need a tmp file then create it before calling awk, e.g. instead of `foo | awk 'script'` you'd do `foo > tmp && awk 'script' tmp` and then parsing it twice is trivially `foo > tmp && awk 'script' tmp tmp`